# How to find the rounded value of 0.00037878768

Tags: javascript, math, logic

I want to calculate some percentage that is creating values 0.0034657, 0.000002376876868, 0.00004557600 etc. like this bt in my react project i want to round the ablove values and print those values 0.0034, 0.0000023, 0.000045 like this. Can please someone tell me logic for this or any arithmatic functions for this.

Values : 0.0034657, 0.000002376876868, 0.00002357600
Expected output : 0.0034, 0.0000023, 0.000023

Comment: so, you want to round to two digits, regardless of the number of zeros ... what have you tried? and it's not rounded, it's "floor"ed, right

Comment: By the way, this question has nothing at all to do with React

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalised solution, you can pass in any number as the second argument

<s>Haven't tested with negative values - deal with that yourself if you need to</s>

Added it for you :p

```js
const special = (v, n = 2) => {
    const s = Math.sign(v);
    if (!s) {
        return 0;
    }
    const digits = 10 ** ((n - 1) - Math.floor(Math.log10(s * v)));
    return s * Math.floor(s * v * digits)/digits;
}
console.log([0, 0.0034657, 0.000002376876868, 0.00002357600, -0.00002357600].map(v => special(v)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `toFixed` method

like this:

```
const roundToDecimal = (value, decimalPlaces) => {
   const rounded = Number(value).toFixed(decimalPlaces);
   return Number(rounded)
}

const values = [0.0034657, 0.000002376876868, 0.00002357600];

const roundedValues = values.map(value => roundToDecimal(value, 4))

console.log(roundedValues);
```

```js
const roundToDecimal = (value, decimalPlaces) => {
   const rounded = Number(value).toFixed(decimalPlaces);
   return Number(rounded)
}

const values = [0.0034657, 0.000002376876868, 0.00002357600];

const roundedValues = values.map(value => roundToDecimal(value, 4))

console.log(roundedValues);
```

Comment: did you try your code?

Answer (score -1):

The below function help you to got 4 or 7 or 6 decimal

```
function roundPercentage(value, decimalPlaces) {
  // Convert the value to a number and round it to the specified decimal places
  const roundedValue = Number(value).toFixed(decimalPlaces);

  // Convert the rounded value back to a number and return it
  return Number(roundedValue);
}

// Example usage:
const value1 = 0.0034657;
const roundedValue1 = roundPercentage(value1, 4); // Round to 4 decimal places
console.log(roundedValue1); // Output: 0.0035

const value2 = 0.000002376876868;
const roundedValue2 = roundPercentage(value2, 7); // Round to 7 decimal places
console.log(roundedValue2); // Output: 0.0000024

const value3 = 0.00002357600;
const roundedValue3 = roundPercentage(value3, 6); // Round to 6 decimal places
console.log(roundedValue3);
```

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for a way to do this ***without*** needing to know beforehand how many digits to use, e.g see @Jaromanda's answer.